# Apache httpd:bind:Address already in use

Tags: linux, apache

When I cross compile appache into DM8168,It appears "httpd:bind:Address already in use".I changed the port 80 to any,such as 8080,90...It doesn't work either.Could anyone tell me why?Thanks for your help.

Comment: Look for duplicates of Listen at your conf files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure port 80 is not used by any other service or application with netstat command:

> netstat -tulpn| grep :80

If port 80 or other port which you assigned (8080,90)is bind to httpd, kill all process:

```
killall -9 httpd
```

Now start the httpd:

```
/etc/init.d/httpd start
```

Also make sure you are root while starting the httpd service.